# Translate 3D MAX file or DAE file with Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, 3dsmax

My developer tried to upload and translate AutoDesk-Forge files from 3D MAX and other with DAE format. However, only the main file can be translated. All the rest of images, labels... are not in. 
We still try and not sure anyone did the same thing. 
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I have not a dataset of 3DMax to test, but with my experience of Obj, you could package the main file and all other images files, and ask Forge to translate, setting the root file with the main file. There might be a possibility Forge Extractor of 3D Max has not supported such way (which i will check with engineer team), but probably you could give a try like Obj that is indicated in this blog:  http://the3dwebcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/06/flipping-obj-axes-with-texture-for-forge-viewer.html

Comment: Thank you, I will check again with your suggestion.

Comment: Hi, We tried with your suggestions. However, we are still not success yet. 
We only can see like: [link](
http://bhtech.com.vn/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/3DMAX_01.png)

We will try with another way same as Revit is to export the model into DWG first.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the work around is convert the source file into DWG, then translate again with Forge. 
Result is: http://117.7.238.88:8308/viewer?path=resources/models/building_models/goodyearpl/dwg.svf

Thanks.

Comment: I was not able to get back soon. It sounds it does not work by zipping the source 3Dmax file package. is it possible you could send us test sample?

Comment: Hi, Right, it cannot work with the zip file. Only source file can be translated. 
Sorry, I cannot send you the source one that we have now, it is a real project. I don't have any example for now.

Comment: ok, I will manage to get a simple test dataset. will keep update this post.

Answer (score 0):

I just got a [simplest dataset](https://autodesk.box.com/s/spmyj7zbei1kzicfnsl7jeesg5aviy9e). One face is attached with a texture material image. I made an zip and sent to Forge services. It looks it can be translated. Could you check my test data anything different to yours?

[image]

Comment: Thanks. 
I will check and get back.